# Pass array of JS object from LWC to Apex as list of string

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, json, convert

From child LWC I want to pass the array of object to Parent LWC which will then pass the object to Apex as List of String

Child.js

```
 allData = [];
        data = {
          id: '',
          startDate : null,
          endDate: null,
          childData : [] 
        };

        someMethod(){
           this.allData.push(this.data);
        }

@api
getAllData(){
//pass this.allData as List<String>
}
```

Parent.js

```
const childAllData = this.template.querySelector('.child').getAllData();
createRecords({
childAllData: childAllData
})
.then(() => {

})
....
```

Apex class

```
public class TextApex{
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void createRecords(List<String> childAllData){
    for(String str : childAllData){
      AllDataResponse res = (AllDataResponse)JSON.deserialize(str, AllDataResponse.class); 
     System.debug(res);
    }
  }

  public class AllDataResponse {
        public Datetime startDate;
        public Datetime endDate;
        public ChildData childData;
    }

    @namespaceAccessible
    public class ChildData{
        public string label;
        public string value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

Data from a child component can be sent to a parent component in an asynchronous way using events. A custom event can be defined for it.

Child component:

```
...
getAllData() {
        const dataEvent = new CustomEvent('childdata', {
            detail: data
        });
        // Fire the custom event
        this.dispatchEvent(dataEvent);
    }
...
```

That event can be caught and handled by the parent LWC (which sends to the Apex Controller) by adding `onchilddata` attribute on the child component in the HTML.

```
<c-child-component onchilddata={handleChildData}>
```

More info can be seen in [this trailhead module.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-from-child-to-parent)

Note that the data should be sent through the different pieces in JSON format, which later can be parsed in the Apex controller to deserialize it as a `List<String>`. You could also serialize it into a String if there are any limitations with the JSON transference in the event.

Comment: Thank you Manuel. 

but I am able to get the data I need in parent lwc already. My question is how do I convert that array of object in parent lwc so it gets passed as List<string> in APEX. 

Currently it throws error saying value defined is invalid for type list